# read a sequence of integers from client and send it to server

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am new to socket programming and i want to read a sequence of integers from the client program and send the array with these integers to the server program and do some calculations there. But how do i do that? the array that im sending with write must be char* ? maybe read a line from stdin and clean it up from other characters than numbers and send it to server and then take each number seperately? but how do i do that? here is my code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

int main() {

    int sockfd, answer=1;
    struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, "askisi3");

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("ERROR connecting");
        exit(1);
    }

    do{
        printf("Enter a sequence of integers.\n");



        //code here...


        printf("Type 0 for exit or any number to continue.\n");
        scanf("%d",&answer)
    }while(answer=0);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The buffer you need to send is a pointer to *const void*. You can pass in pointer to *any* object (however be aware that it might be non-portable

Comment: "*the array that im sending with write must be `char*`*" A `char*` is exactly ***one*** pointer, storing exactly ***one*** pointer value. No chance to store a string and integer or what ever else.

Answer (score 1):

We are not going to write the key code for you, but in answer to your specific questions:

> the array that im sending with write must be char* ?

The first thing to understand is that from the perspective of the communication channel itself, there are no arrays and no pointers, only a stream of bytes.

The second thing to understand is that the value of a pointer itself is meaningful only to one process, so sending *that* is useless.  You may, however, want to send some or all of the data to which a given pointer points.  In fact, that's precisely what the `write()` function does -- it sends some number of the bytes to which the provided pointer points.

The third thing to understand is that the details of what you should send depend on some kind of agreement between the communicating parties about what will be sent and in what form it will be sent.  This is called an application-layer "protocol" (not to be confused with a network protocol such as TCP).  Since you are writing both client and server, *you* get to choose that protocol.

> maybe read a line from stdin and clean it up from other characters than numbers and send it to server and then take each number seperately?

That would be a viable alternative.

> but how do i do that?

That is too broad a question for this venue.